# How to print a string out of a Class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have made a class that returns a string that may append or delete a input value.

I have to pass my test through the following assert if the stack class is empty:

```
assert print(Stack()) == ''
```

I have tried to use the **str** and **repr**, but with no success.

My class is defined as follow:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ''
        self.final_value = ''

    def __repr__(self):
        for i in range(self.size()):
            if i == 0:
                self.final_value += str(self.data[i])
            else:
                self.final_value += ' -> ' + str(self.data[i])
        return str(self.final_value)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.data) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def push(self, value_to_add):
        if type(value_to_add) is int or type(value_to_add) is str:
            self.data = str(value_to_add) + self.data
        elif callable(value_to_add):
            self.data = 'F' + self.data
        elif type(value_to_add) is dict:
            self.data = 'D' + self.data
        elif type(value_to_add) is list:
            self.data = 'L' + self.data
        elif value_to_add is None:
            self.data = 'N' + self.data
        return self.data

    def add(self, value_to_add):
        if type(value_to_add) is int or type(value_to_add) is str:
            self.data = str(value_to_add) + self.data
        elif callable(value_to_add):
            self.data = 'F' + self.data
        elif type(value_to_add) is dict:
            self.data = 'D' + self.data
        elif type(value_to_add) is list:
            self.data = 'L' + self.data
        elif value_to_add is None:
            self.data = 'N' + self.data
        return self.data

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise StackPopException
        else:
            value_to_pop = self.data[0]
            self.data = self.data[1:]
        return int(value_to_pop)

    def size(self):
        return len(self.data)


StackPopException = ValueError
```

When I run the following test my code fails due to the type of the returned value:

```
stack = Stack()

stack.push(3)
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)

assert print(stack) == '2 -> 1 -> 3'
```

**EDIT**

How can I make that work without changing the test line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `assert str(stack) == '2 -> 1 -> 3'` to force the class to return the string representation of itself.

**After question edit:**
The print-function returns `None` so the return value cannot be used for testing.

Comment: @MatheusSant'ana But the test as it is written is incorrect, `print` returns `None` regardless of what it prints

Comment: Got it, that was in my mind as well. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @MatheusSant'ana So will you change the test?

Comment: I gess so... I did not make that test, my code should pass through the test, but I got stucked into that part.

Answer (score 0):

Try `assert repr(stack) == "'2 -> 1 -> 3'"` (mind the exact usage of quotes).

Comment: The thing is that I can't change the test. I have tried to change it to assert str(stack) == '2 -> 1 -> 3' and it worked, but I can't do that.

Comment: But the test as it is written is incorrect, `print` returns `None`